# How can I refer to multiple aggregation functions in data.table dcast?

Tags: r, data.table, dcast

I want to put data.table `dcast` function into a function, which can handle custom number/order of aggregate functions. That is why I need to pass aggregate functions as parameters to `dcast` function. The parameters need to be defined outside `dcast`.
How could I do this?

This works well, but I wan to define the aggregate functions outside of dcast.

```
dt = data.table(x = sample(5, 20, TRUE), y = sample(2, 20, TRUE), 
                z = sample(letters[1:2], 20, TRUE), d1 = runif(20), d2 = 1L

dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun = list(sum, min), value.var = "d1")
```

I tried this method:

```
func <- list(sum, min)

dcast(dt, x + y ~ z, fun = func, value.var = "d1")
```

Then I get this error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "func"

Comment: I think this is the same bug: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1369

Comment: It works on the actual versiosn of the `data.table`.